# Capacitance matrix is diagonally dominant

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, capacitance, conductors

I have heard of the following claim “the capacitance matrix of an isolated system of conductors is diagonally dominant” but I couldn’t find a way of proving it myself or any reference for that matter. Does anyone know how to prove it or where to find a rigorous proof?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [the article by John Denker](http://www.av8n.com/physics/capacitance.htm) is useful as an explanation of capacity matrices.

Suppose we have two capacitors, one with a capacitance of 10 µF and the other with a capacitance of 20 pF.
Arrange them as shown in the figure and join the bottom conductors of the two capacitors to make a three-conductor problem. (The original picture is taken from Wikipedia(jpn)).

[image: 3 conductors problem]

Symbolize capacitance as $C_A(=10\mu F), C_B(=20pF)$, and assign conductor numbers as shown in the figure.  The capacitance matrix for a three-conductor system is as follows,
\begin{equation*}
C=
\begin{pmatrix}
C_{11} & C_{12} & C_{13} \\
C_{21} & C_{22} & C_{23} \\
C_{31} & C_{32} & C_{33}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
C_A & -C_A & 0 \\
-C_A & C_A+C_B & -C_B \\
0 & -C_B & C_B
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
Since conductors 1 and 3 are not coupled, the corresponding component ($C_{13}$) is set to 0.
We chose $C_{33}$ as the representative of the diagonal component
and $C_{12}$ as the representative of the off-diagonal component,
and calculated the ratio of their magnitudes.
\begin{equation*}
\text{ratio}=\frac{-C_{12}}{C_{33}}=\frac{10\mu F}{20pF}=5.0\times 10^5
\end{equation*}

Therefore, the statement "the capacitance matrix of an isolated system of conductors is diagonally dominant" is false.

Comment: I am sorry but I couldn’t follow why the matrix is not diagonally dominant. It seems to me that the definition is satisfied (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix where I am considering the weak definition).

Comment: @Matteo Menghini, I did not know that the term diagonal dominance of a matrix had a rigorous definition. I thought that if the diagonal component was small enough compared to the non-diagonal terms, then it was not diagonally dominant. My description must be wrong. My apologies.